# WPF Popup Activation and Deactivation

Tags: wpf

Is there a possibility to detect if a Popup is activated or deactivated? Such as the Window-events `Window.Activated` and `Window.Deactivated`.

I want to detect if the user has clicked outside of the popup (I can not use the `Popup.StaysOpen=false` option).

**Update**

I have forgotten to remark, that I dont want to add any handler or code to a parent-control of the popup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capture mouse clicks for your main application window (MousePreview type event) and for popup - when user clicks into popup, main window event doesn't fire and vice versa.

Comment: +1 I think you mean using CaptureMouse() and ReleaseCaptureMouse(). Yes, thats the way to go. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you could just use the [`Popup.Opened`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup.opened.aspx) and [`Popup.Closed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup.closed.aspx) events.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sadly I can not use these events, because I have StaysOpen=true and therefore the popup never closes and the Closed-event will not fire.